# How do I support a deck that spans a driveway?

Tags: deck

I am planning to reinforce my deck, as it is has a lot of sway, and was built with 12' 4x4s, and not 6x6s. The deck spans my driveway, which is the width of a two car garage, so a fairly decent span. Should I look at installing some type of braces for this span, or will posts on either side of the driveway be enough?

Comment: Did the swaying deck pass muster with the building inspector when it was originally constructed?

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Is the deck 12' in the air? How many 4x4s are there, how far apart are they, what is the size of the beams, and what is the size of the joists?

Comment: x bracing is a good way to stabilize, recommended by many codes for elevated structures.

Comment: Bolts and galv L brackets?  Ours spans our driveway as well and was recently constructed.  It is bolted to the driveway and they have L brackets and a lot of timber under there.

Comment: -1 due to lack of follow up. This question should likely be closed because of insufficient details.

Comment: It'd be nice if any support posts near the driveway were reinforced to the extent that they could take the impact of a vehicle without failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can install bracing from 4' down on the post at a 45degree angle to the bottom of the header that is so panning the driveway. Use 1/2" x 6" lags to make the connection thru the new 4 x 4 bracing. Make sure that the brace doesn't interfere with getting a car in and out of the garage

Comment: Would it provide any benefit if the bracing was higher, and not at a 45 degree angle? I think that 4' might be too close to the car.

Answer (score 1):

Use wood or metal strapping diagonally along the bottom of the joists.

[image: lateral Bracing Strapping]

Comment: What material is this strapping? I'm not seeing how it would add much strength.

Comment: Steel or wood. It is for lateral stability, not "strength" and would help stop "sway". It is the same method for bracing walls in a home if there is no plywood/sheathing.